# Short story with amphetamine, barbiturate and luminous paint

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story when I was about 14 in 1968ish possibly in the John Carnell series [*New Writings in SF*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Writings_in_SF) in which, as I remember, there were a man and a woman, one of them strung out on speed and the other on barbiturate. The woman painted herself with luminous/fluorescent paint, I think.

Comment: Could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? Also what parts of this story were science fiction or fantasy in nature? At the moment I can't see anything.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - "in the John Carnell series New Writings in *SF*"

Comment: Although I suppose that could mean San Francisco.

Comment: @RDFozz Aye I missed that initially, it is clearer now Skoob has added the link though. There still isn't anythign about the story that strikes me as SFF-nal just where it was, however.

Comment: re editing, I just typed it in. A paragraph disappeared but it was just me saying thanks etc. Def a SF collection, and well some Aldiss etc doesn't clearly tick the SF box, think "Ther moment of eclipse" kind of feel. And thank you !!

Comment: duh sorry, I read it as "in which I can edit"! I honestly can't remember any more than that. But it's one that's bugged me off and on over the years as I've continued consuming SF. I don't do Fantasy - one sword or wizard and I'm out of there!